# Unit testing async method: The remote hostanme could not be resolved

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

I am trying to test some async methods involving the HttpClient work with vs 2012 express for win 8 and it's test framework. No matter how I try I always get the same exception.

For example this test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Connect()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string reply = await client.GetStringAsync("http://google.com");
    Assert.AreNotEqual(0, reply.Length);
}
```

Which should probably work considering this: http://www.richard-banks.org/2012/03/how-to-unit-test-async-methods-with.html

Throws

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'google.com'
```

The same code works just fine when called from an actual program (not a test case).
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the test case work if you do it synchronously?

Comment: Is there a way to do so in .net 4.5? I can only see async request methods within the HttpClient class.

Comment: Right, `HttpClient` doesn't have synchronous method. But you can try something like `client.GetStringAsync(url).Result`.

Comment: That was the first thing I've tried, even before I figured out that test case can return `Task`. Result is the same.

Comment: Are you are using the metro style Unit Testing template? If yes you need to enable the Internet Client (I think) in the app manifest file -> capabilities to allow this behaviour?. Also since you are testing an external call, this is not a Unit Test. It is more of an integration test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to my comments and I can include this as an answer to your question.

"*Are you are using the metro style Unit Testing template? If yes you need to enable the Internet Client (I think) in the app manifest file -> capabilities to allow this behaviour?. Also since you are testing an external call, this is not a Unit Test. It is more of an integration test.*"

I have used exactly the same code you have and I get exactly the same error. As I said if you just tick the the Package.appxmanifest -> Capabilities - > Internet (Client) check box, you test should pass.

Comment: Thank you for your answer `Package.appxmanifest` was obviuosly the issue. Though I cannot really say that code provided earlier by me works -- VS crashes each time I try to run the provided test with Internet (Client) capabilities enabled.